# WordPress: Save editor inline style in AMP

Tags: css, wordpress, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

I want to use an inline style from the WordPress editor in my AMP view.
At the moment, AMP deletes all inline styles.

Is there a way to protect a single class and use it in AMP or is it against the concept of AMP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer!
You could use the class `.amp-custom` to keep inline-styles in AMP.